# How to draw a average line across bars in a google bar charts?

Tags: google-visualization

I need to draw a average line across the bars in the google bar charts as shown in image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3aII.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

in the chart options, add a trendline, to see the average for the series

use the series number the trendline should represent...

```
      trendlines: {
        // 0 = first series
        0: {
          type: 'linear'
        }
      }
```